# Type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>' in type cast in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

While fetching the list of data from Firebase Firestore using Stream Builder in the StreamSubcription listener fetching it as QuerySnapshot and is not able to cast to a List.

```
    late StreamSubcription _listener;
    final _controller = BehaviorSubject<List<Object>>(); 
    Stream<List<Journey>> get getList => _controller.stream.distinct(); 


    Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> firestoredataStream = 
        FirebaseFirestore.instance 
            .collection('journeys') 
            .where('userID', isEqualTo: _user.email) 
            .snapshots(); 

    _listener = firestoredataStream.listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) { 
      if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) { 
        _controller.add(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => mapSnapshotToObject(doc)).toList() as List<Object>); 
      } 
    });
```

Even it gives an error in debug mode for Typecast.
please rectify this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `.cast()` method to safely cast the elements of your list to the desired type.

```dart
_listener = firestoredataStream.listen((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
    final List<Journey> journeys = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => mapSnapshotToObject(doc)).toList();

    _controller.add(journeys.cast<Object>().toList());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the data returned from firestore is nullable, whereas your BehaviorSubject decleration only accepts non-null objects.

Change

```
final _controller = BehaviorSubject<List<Object>>();
```

to this:

```
final _controller = BehaviorSubject<List<Object?>>();
```

When consuming your stream later in your code, you will need to handle the fact that sometimes the list can contain nullable objects.